# Match string after newline

Tags: java, regex, newline

Within Java I have this string:

```
uk\learningAid\UserInputs\UserClass.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
player.mvRight(3);
```

I am currently using this regex to match `16` and `cannot find symbol`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":(\\d+):\\serror:\\s(.*)");
```

However, I want to also match `player.mvRight(3);` which is on a new line. How do I do this?

I tried adding this `\\n(.*)` at the end of the reex, but it failed to match anything.

Comment: Use `Pattern.compile("...", Pattern.DOTALL)` <-- this will make the dot match newlines

Comment: `Pattern.DOTALL` overrides the regex `.` functionality of not matching any new lines. However, for me this also retrieves text after `player.mvRight(3);`. I just want to match `player.mvRight(3);` and nothing after.

Comment: Then you have to be a little more precise about your possible inputs and the expected outputs

Comment: Does it have to be with regex? Couldn't you just use the provided `String` methods?

Comment: @RudiKershaw I am open to anything. Can you show an example?

Comment: @user3166216 - Sure, posted an answer for you to look over.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? If so, don't forget to upvote and accept an answer. If none of the below are how you resolved the issue you can post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To match including new line up to the first ";".

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":(\\d)+:\\serror:\\s(.*)\\n(.*);");
```

Comment: It should be noted that the use of `\s` is probably a bad idea in the above example, as this will match any whitespace character, not just normal spaces.  Given the input, this would make more sense instead: 
`:(\\d)+: error: (.*)\\n(.*);`

Comment: The pattern I used just added on top of the pattern the author used. Otherwise, your alternative should do as well for the reasons stated.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments, if it doesn't necessarily need to be regex then the `String` methods such as `substring()` and `indexof()` can be used to get the position of certain characters and use those as markers for any strings with a certain pattern. The below SSCCE should work for your `String` and any of a similar format.

```
public  class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String toProcess = "uk\\learningAid\\UserInputs\\UserClass.java:16: error: cannot find symbol \nplayer.mvRight(3);";
        int firstCol = toProcess.indexOf(":");
        int secondCol = toProcess.indexOf(":", firstCol+1);
        int lastCol = toProcess.lastIndexOf(":");
        System.out.println(toProcess.substring(firstCol+1, secondCol) + toProcess.substring(lastCol+1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
16 cannot find symbol 
player.mvRight(3);
```

Also, if you want the line break removed you can just call `toProcess = toProcess.replaceAll("\n", "");` at the beginning to remove the line breaks.